# Как правильно вставлять дату из excel в postgresql через java код

Tags: java, postgresql, excel, javafx

мне нужно вставить дату из excel в мою таблицу Postgresql через JavaFX при помощи `ctrl + v`.
Дата в excel у меня записана 05.01.2021 при вставке с помощью `ctrl + v` я обрабатываю вот таким вот кодом:

```
// clipboardCellContent это данные которые приходят из буфера, и приходят они в String формате
 
 SimpleDateFormat dateToDB = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    // dateQuery - java.UTIL.Date думал сначала так, а потов в java.sql.Date
                    Date dateQuery = null;
                    try {
                        dateQuery = dateToDB.parse(clipboardCellContent);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    table.getItems().get(rowTable).setDate(dateQuery);
```

Но на выходе из кода у меня выходит вот такой формат времени:
`Tue Jan 05 00:00:00: UZT 2021` что совершенно мне не подходит

Comment: что занчит выходит вот такой формат времени? где вы это видите? это вывод в консоль?

Comment: Это я проверил дебагом

Answer (score 0):

Я решил вопрос обычным алгоритмом, просто, я переделал строку из 05.01.2021 в 2021-01-05 (Формат строки которую может обрабатывать java.sql.Date) при помощи вот этого кода:

```
 private static String dateTransform(String dataItem){

// создаем массив элементов из строки, каждый элемент отделяется точкой
        String[] arrayString = dataItem.split("\\.");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//проходимся по массиву берем элемент и ставим в начало
        for(int i = arrayString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(!(i == 0)){
                builder.append(arrayString[i]).append("-");
            }
            else {
// если элемент последний то "-" ставить не нужно
                builder.append(arrayString[i]);
            }
        }
        return builder.toString().trim();
    }
```

Не уверен в логичности действия, но по мне так это лучше чем мучиться с этими ужасными
java.util.Date и SimpleDateFormate

Comment: нет, не лучше. вы превратили дату в строку. это очень радует глаз в дебагере или консоли, но на этом преимущества заканчиваются. объект типа даты содержит методы, позволяющие проделывать операции, специфические для даты (например, понять какой это день недели, или вычислить временной промежуток между датами). а со строкой вы не можете сделать ничего. как только появится такая необходимость (а она появится), вам придется крутить костыли по всему коду, чтобы сделать элементарные для объекта типа даты вещи

Comment: Дело в том, что из Буфера (так как я вставляю дату по средством ctrl+c, ctrl + v) так или иначе, в любом случае она приходит в виде строки я просто строку переделываю в строку а потом строку превращаю в sql формат даты

Comment: так может тогда лучше парсить данные прямо из экселевской таблицы? apache poi никто не отменял вроде...